# Is it possible to vassalise a nation that already owns a vassal?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

**Is it possible to vassalise a nation that already owns a vassal ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this  is possible, but only through a peace treaty. If you try this via diplomatic means you will get -1000 points in the weighing criteria for their answer, meaning it will never happen.